# ListView selector and shape : how to set textcolor?

Tags: android, listview, shapes, textcolor

I have a ListView as my app's slidermenu.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

`list_selector.xml` in drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

`list_item_bg_normal.xml` :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:startColor="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

I tried to add `android:color` or `android:textColor` attributes but nothing seems to work. What to do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you mean textColor to each of the item in the listView?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin That's it, sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Where is  the textview of your item defined?